# Remove Android Emulator from Run list android-studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have created a few android emulators but for some reason some of them are not working (i can see them running on background but cant display them on screen.
anyway to remove them from the list so i dont have to run them again in future by mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Tools->AVD Manager->Select Delete** from dropdown for the virtual device you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools 
Click on **Avd Manager**

Now you will see the list of emulator devices you have already created.

Click on DropDown Icon [image]